filter array of objects and get properties into a new array dynamically
I have input as follows
[
    {
        "metadata": { "id": 1071, "name": "First" },
        "languages": [
            { "name": "Alpha", "details": [ { "city": "usa", "count": 33 } ] },
            { "name": "Beta", "details": [ { "city": "japan", "count": 3 } ] },
        ]
    },
    {
        "metadata": { "id": 1068, "name": "Second" },
        "languages": [
            { "name": "Alpha", "details": [ { "city": "japan", "count": 10 }, { "city": "usa", "count": 20 } ] },
            { "name": "Beta", "details": [ { "city": "japan", "count": 15 }, { "city": "usa", "count": 25 } ] },
        ]
    },
]

So here is my scenario where i have to filter by language Alpha. So i have to go through first object and filter languages by Alpha and then get usa and japan count into a new array. Similarly loop through 2nd object and extract that count.
At the end, i should get below sequence of counts in the new array
output = { japan: [0, 10], usa: [33, 20] } //for filter by Alpha
output = { japan: [3, 15], usa: [0, 25] } //for filter by Beta

I am able to achieve the above output by using the below code.
const filterBy = (data, name) => {
    return data.reduce((p, c) => {
        for (let langObj of c.languages) {
            if (langObj.name === name) {
                const groupedOnCityCount = langObj.details.reduce((x, {city,count}) => ({ ...x, [city]: count }), {});
                p.usa.push(groupedOnCityCount?.usa || 0);
                p.japan.push(groupedOnCityCount?.japan || 0);
            }
        }
        return p;
    }, { japan: [], usa: [] });
}

const A = filterBy(data, 'Alpha');
const B = filterBy(data, 'Beta');

Everything uptil here works fine. The problem arises if the input is dynamic. i.e. we dont know if the output will only include japan and usa (its not static)
Here is the dynamic input i am expecting now instead of earlier static input.
[
    {
        "metadata": { "id": 1071, "name": "First" },
        "languages": [
            { "name": "Alpha", "details": [ { "city": "usa", "count": 33 }, { "city": "korea", "count": 20 } ] },
            { "name": "Beta", "details": [ { "city": "japan", "count": 3 } ] },
        ]
    },
    {
        "metadata": { "id": 1068, "name": "Second" },
        "languages": [
            { "name": "Alpha", "details": [] },
            { "name": "Beta", "details": [ { "city": "japan", "count": 15 }, { "city": "russia", "count": 77 } ] },
        ]
    },
]

As per above input, some languages may contain additional cities which doesnot exist in other objects. Also some may have empty details:[]
For above input, i want desired output
output = { usa: [33, 0] korea: [20, 0 ] } //for filter by Alpha
output = { japan: [3, 15], russia: [0, 77] } //for filter by Beta

Can someone let me know how to dynamically get this.

why alpha doesnt have russia, but has japan. similarly for beta

that is the sort of dynamic data i am getting. Above input, i have korea, japan and usa for alpha, japan and russia in beta.

but then how to know logically if russia is included with [0,0] or removed completely in alpha

we filter by alpha or beta and then see which cities are included for that object ?

then why is japan: [0, 0] included in your expected output for alpha in your dynamic example if japan isn't a city in details when you filter for alpha?

my bad, i updated the question with correct output expected

But if you filter on alpha, you get 3 details object, without japan, how can we dynamically catch that to add japan: [ 0, 0 ]?

no, filter by alpha will get 2 (usa and korea).

Does the order matter? Is russia: [0, 77] and russia: [77,0] both OK?

yea order matters

https://codeshare.io/zlXpkE  extension to your previous question

You could reduce the array and get the information from nested items.


const
    filter = (array, value) => array.reduce((r, { languages }, i, a) => {
        languages.some(({ name, details }) => {
            if (name === value) {
                details.forEach(({ city, count }) => {
                    r[city] ??= Array(a.length).fill(0);
                    r[city][i] = count;
                })
                return true;
            }
        });    
        return r;
    }, {}),
    data = [{ metadata: { id: 1071, name: "First" }, languages: [{ name: "Alpha", details: [{ city: "usa", count: 33 }, { city: "korea", count: 20 }] }, { name: "Beta", details: [{ city: "japan", count: 3 }] }] }, { metadata: { id: 1068, name: "Second" }, languages: [{ name: "Alpha", details: [] }, { name: "Beta", details: [{ city: "japan", count: 15 }, { city: "russia", count: 77 }] }] }],
    result1 = filter(data, 'Alpha'),
    result2 = filter(data, 'Beta');

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




is there an alternative for using ??= It gives compilation error. probably the project doesnot support this syntax.

@ArenTrot try r[city] = r[city] || Array(a.length).fill(0);
